# Change Content Type for SharePoint 2010 Wiki to Create Custom New Page

Tags: 2010, content-type, custom, wiki, provisioning

Here is what I want to accomplish:

Inside of a Wiki Library, user says they need a new page and creates one using the [[ ]] syntax. Then when the user clicks that new link, they are asked to create a new page. Instead of a blank page being created, I want the page to have a layout and fields like `Enter Description Here` and `Select a Topic` with a drop-down menu.

I was able to create a content type and page layout but I'm not sure how to get the Wiki to use the new page layout instead of the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable publishing feature. Then

**Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Page Layouts and Site Templates**

Here you can set the default page layout.

Comment: The publishing feature was already set. I set the default page layout to my custom wiki page layout. Then i went to my wiki library page to create a new page using the [[]] method. When i clicked the link to create a new page, it still created the page using the blank template. @amalhashim

Comment: @Kizzie as per [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/f8f9ece6-92a3-47db-9c04-b4c3115522e5/changing-page-layout-used-by-newpage-link-in-enterprise-wiki) thread the setting needs to be saved twice. Give it a try.